# how "request->getBody" works in slim

Tags: php, functional-programming, slim

If I do a post, I can get content by doing `$payload = json_decode($app->request->getBody());`

But I cannot understand how `request->getBody` works in slim.

First, there's a magic method :

```
public function __get($name)
{
    return $this->container->get($name);
}
```

This will return a Slim\Http\Request object. That's fine for now.

`$this->container` is the Slim\Helper\Set, and this is the get function :

```
public function get($key, $default = null)
{
    if ($this->has($key)) {
        $isInvokable = is_object($this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)]) && method_exists($this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)], '__invoke');

        return $isInvokable ? $this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)]($this) : $this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)];
    }

    return $default;
}
```

`$this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)]` is the same as `$this->data['request']`, which is something of type "Closure" (not sure to understand this).

`$isInvokable` is true, so this is called :

```
$this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)]($this)
```

What is this line doing ? Why the `($this)` (Slim\Helper\Set) at the end ?

Especially, why the next function to be called is this :

```
public function singleton($key, $value)
{
    $this->set($key, function ($c) use ($value) {
        static $object;

        if (null === $object) {
            $object = $value($c);
        }

        return $object;
    });
}
```

Why `singleton($key, $value)` ?
It has never been called ! 
$key is not defined at the start of the function. Also what makes $c a Slim\Helper\Set, and $value a closure ?

And why the execution of only `static $object` makes the $object goes from unitialized to one of type Slim\Http\Request ?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Slim. I'm just going by what you've posted.

Well, the `Set->get()` method tests, if the value in the `data` property array with the key `$key` can be invoked, and then does it, if true.

So `$this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)]($this)` is calling a method with `$this` given as parameter and then `Set->get()` returns that method's return value.

A closure is also often called an "[anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php)", which is a new feature as of PHP 5.3. Using an array as [variable to call a function](http://php.net/manual/functions.variable-functions.php) is available since PHP 5.4.

It allows you to pass around functions/methods as values, which is arguably *the* distinctive feature in [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Function singleton is called before in the initialization.

It is setting all $key to a function.

So, `$this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)]($this)` is that function !